# analytics.js, how to track event?

Tags: statistics, analytics

I need to track all click on the button in my form.

In head section i have GA code

```
            <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'xxx', 'auto');

        ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
```

and I add a code to tracking my button

```
jQuery("#myButton").click(function() { ga('send', 'event', 'Rezerwacje', 'Zamowienie rezerwacji przez formularz WWW', 'Zamowienie'); })
```

But in doesn't work and i have 0 all the time in analytics. What i do wrong?

In debugger after click on button i got it [debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7bgp.png)

Comment: do you see any errors or do you see an AJAX in your developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign');

ga('send', {
  hitType: 'event',
  eventCategory: 'Videos',
  eventAction: 'play',
  eventLabel: 'Fall Campaign'
});
```

Comment: i have it in my code `ga('send', 'event', 'Rezerwacje', 'Zamowienie rezerwacji przez formularz WWW', 'Zamowienie');`